# JIRA - How to populate Select List from external SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, drop-down-menu, jira

In JIRA, how can I connect to a SQL table and set the options for a Select List (or similar control) by querying the SQL database?

I have been trying to use the Kepler plugin for Database Custom Field, but it has not yet worked, and the only error that I can find in the output that might be the problem is:

> Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' for connect URL 'sql-admin'

My connection string, in the `context.xml`, is:

```
<Resource name="cds-admin"
      auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      username="cds_user"
      password="XXXXX"
      driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sql-admin:1433;instance=SQL-ADMIN"
 />
```

And this file exists in the `/lib` directory: `jtds-1.2.4.jar`

Anyone have any thoughts on why this might not be working, or have any other solution?

EDIT:

The plug-in now works.  I excluded the port number from the .xml item, and I updated the .jar to jtds-1.3.1 - and now I've got my dropdown populated with sql driven data.

Thanks.

Comment: Just write an answer, explain there your solution so that others may understand later, why that is a solution, and then accept your own answer later. Else the question will open to the end of time ... :-)